# Teradata: Insert Into Table results of Selects

Tags: select, insert, teradata

How do I insert into a table the values that result from various selects? For example, the code below comes out empty:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TEST (CAMPO1 INT, CAMPO2 INT);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( (select 1), (SELECT 2) );

SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

The result is a table Test empty. The results of "select 1" and "select 2" were not inserted into Test. Is it possible to insert the values one by one as results of other selects?

Comment: You must include `on commit preserve rows` at the end of your create volatile table statement.  For some reason (that I don't get at all), the default is `on commit delete rows`.

Comment: @Andrew The default comes from Standard SQL and it is ok there, because you must explicitly commit a transaction, while TD autocommits every request in a Teradata session (but not in an ANSI session)

Comment: @dnoeth, all these years, I never knew that! Never occurred to me to view it as a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The Inserts were successfull, but the table was emptied when they committed :-)

The syntax to create Volatile or Global Temporary tables is based on Standard and thus the default `ON COMMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, which is quite useless in a Teradata session.

Youneed to switch to

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TEST (CAMPO1 INT, CAMPO2 INT) ON COMMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @dnoeth. All the best. Eduardo.